# How to fix "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ."

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up a reset button by which ll the existing filters will be reset.
Reset button is working fine but I am getting  console error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .

[image]

in this line of my js code:

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','#reset_team_time_sheet', function(){

    //error in these two lines, If I remove these lines the error is not coming
    $('.deselect_filter_values').val('').change();
    $('#group_by_team_time_sheet').val('day').change();

    $('.time-sheet-filter').removeClass('active');
});
```

HTML code:

```
//this is my reset button
<a id="reset_team_time_sheet" class="reset reset-time-sheet" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadTimeSheetData('2019-04-25', '2019-04-25', '', 'team')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Reset">Reset</a>

//Filter
<select name="selected_user" id="user_id_filter_team_time_sheet" class="form-control select2 deselect_filter_values " select2width="140px" select2placeholder="Filter User" data-select2-id="user_id_filter_team_time_sheet" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option data-type="" value="" data-select2-id="6">Filter User</option>                                                                                                                        
  <option data-type="students" value="326" data-select2-id="18">Adam Adcc</option>  
  <option data-type="students" value="328" data-select2-id="19">Admon Connolly</option>
  <option data-type="students" value="479" data-select2-id="20">Alex Ladd</option>                                                                                                                                    
  <option data-type="students" value="296" data-select2-id="21">Alexandra  Bose</option>                                                                                                                                    
  <option data-type="students" value="494" data-select2-id="22">Alysha Zimmermann</option>                                                                                                                                    
  <option data-type="students" value="17733" data-select2-id="23">Ashlea McKenzie</option>
```

Please help to solve this console error.

Comment: Can you edit a runnable snippet into your question that illustrates the problem? (don't post images of code, post the actual code)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, the problem is in something you haven't posted - perhaps in a `change` event handler

Comment: Jquery 2.1.1 is a really old version. Perhaps the . selector is not supported

Comment: It also looks like the syntax error is thrown by code, not the interpreter

Comment: Seems error throws from facebook sdk, are you using fb sdk in your project or anything related to fb - fb api ?

Comment: yes I am using fb_loader